# Disable TLSv1.0 on Nginx (PCI-DSS compilance)

Tags: ssl, nginx, tls1.2

I've changed to this settings, but TLSv1.0 is still appearing on the testing.

Can anyone help please?

**cat /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf**

```
ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS";
```

**cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Comment: (1) You means TLS not TSL and PCI-DSS not SSD. (2) Are these settings global to `http` or within one or more `server` block(s)? (3) Did you restart or reload nginx after the change? (4) How exactly are you testing? In particular could you be hitting something else like a firewall/IDS/IPS/WAF/LB/CDN not this server?

Comment: 1) Wow, sorry, this was in a hurry
2) This is global on the http
3) Yes, I've restarted
4) I'm behind CDN (Stackpath), but I've checked minimun TLS version to be 1.2

Comment: If you're using a CDN, it is _their_ TLS capabilities and settings that matter for connecting browsers/clients, not your server's. I'm not familiar with Stackpath; maybe someone else is.

Comment: So much thanks, finally the problem was with the CDN TLS

Answer (score 0):

You might have too many `ssl_ciphers`.

The values below come from [Recommendations for TLS/SSL Cipher Hardening](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/tls-ssl-cipher-hardening/) and their comments state it is used to "Enable modern TLS cipher suites". I have to warn you, we have only used this on a staging server:

```
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
```